# after moving to sharepoint 2019 and to run site over https i get problems opening files

Tags: internet-explorer, sharepoint, https, gpo

I'm having some trouble after switch to https

We use our **own application** that connect to our Sharepoint webapp with URL to upload and edit files.
I moved from Sharepoint 2013 to 2019 and everything was working as long as I used http. But after changing to https we have trouble opening some types of files.

I have added the the server to GPO for trusted zone in internet option. Word and excel documents open with the computers app as it should, but .csv , .pdf and jpg a windows popup with a warning about not safe file. Then i can press OK but nothing is happening. file won't open and no message or anything...

If i access the sharepoint site through a web browser everything is working. word and excel Csv gets downloaded and I can open them. pdf and jpg opened in web browser.

Hope some one can understand what my problem is here or guide me in the right direction

Answer (score 0):

> Word and excel documents open with the computers app as it should, but .csv , .pdf and jpg a windows popup with a warning about not safe file.

Based on what you have described above, I think they should be related to mixed content download. I'm guessing that the files are still downloaded from the http link, hence the problem.

In order to solve this problem, you need to use the matching policy: [InsecureContentAllowedForUrls](https://learn.microsoft.com/en-us/deployedge/microsoft-edge-policies#insecurecontentallowedforurls). It is used to create a list of URL patterns to specify sites that can display or download insecure mixed content (HTTP content on HTTPS sites). Located under this path: `Administrative Templates/Microsoft Edge/Content settings`.

For more details, please refer to this docment: [Learn about Microsoft Edge and mixed content downloads](https://learn.microsoft.com/en-us/deployedge/edge-learnmore-mixed-content-downloads#what-are-mixed-content-downloads).

Comment: This does not seem to help in this case. any more ideas?

Comment: Does chrome have the same problem? Does it work if you hit `keep` option when the `unsafe file` warning pops up?

Comment: it's not opened in the web browser. Our program open the files with URLs to the sharepoint. It should open with the right program on the computer directly. (we do get warnings tho) And it was working before switching to https. It is working as i should if I access the site in a web broswer.

Comment: Does downloading such files from other https sites have the same issue? And as I asked above, is clicking the keep option able to download and save the file?

Comment: There is no problem using a web brower